# disable default log configuration in jboss eap 6.3 or jboss eap 6.3 log4j configuration should not contain stdout statements?

Tags: java, log4j, jboss-eap-6

below is my `logconfig.xml` file where i configured the log, problem is here i don't want any `stdout` statements in `myLogs.log` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="null" threshold="null">
<appender name="INFO_FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="mypath/myLogs.log"/>  
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'MM-dd-yy"/>
        <layout class="class path here">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %c{2} %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="INFO_FILE"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

myLogs.log this file contains stdout logs but i don't want stdout statement, this file should contain only other statements excepts stdout

```
2015-11-20 02:14:08,829 stdout setSessionContext()
2015-11-20 02:14:08,830 stdout ejbCreate()
2015-11-20 02:14:08,830 stdout getNewsRowSet()
2015-11-20 02:14:08,831 stdout newbean1
2015-11-20 02:14:08,831 stdout newbean2
2015-11-20 02:14:08,832 stdout newbean3
2015-11-20 02:14:08,832 stdout newbean4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove the logging `subsystem` from `configuration/domain.xml` file. It will disable your `jboss eap's` default logging and your configuration will work

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.4">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
```

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question*.